# Compose variable in twig with active language

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a variable with the name category.nameNl. When I dump this it works fine and shows the name of the category.

```
{{ dump(category.nameNl) }}
```

Now I want to make it dynamically with the active language, so nameEn en nameDe are also working. I tread the following but this is not working:

```
{{ dump(category.name~app.request.locale|capitalize) }}
```

Any idea?

Comment: `(category.name~app.request.locale)|capitalize`

Comment: The capitalize needs only be performed on the app.request.locale so 'Nl' has the capital and not the complete variablename.

Answer (score 4):

The filter operator (`|`) has higher precedence than the concatenation operator (`~`) so the capitalization happens first.

If you want to capitalize the resulting string, you'll have to use parentheses:

```
{{ dump((category.name~app.request.locale)|capitalize) }}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#twig-expressions

> The operator precedence is as follows, with the lowest-precedence operators listed first: b-and, b-xor, b-or, or, and, ==, !=, <, >, >=, <=, in, matches, starts with, ends with, .., +, -, ~, *, /, //, %, is, **, |, [], and .

Comment: Lookt like the ~ is not working, I'm getting the error that the variable name is unknown.

Comment: Then try this to see all of the defined variables: `{{ dump() }}`

Comment: The variable category.nameNl is there and works with {{ dump(category.nameNl) }}

Comment: `attribute(category, 'name'~app.request.locale|capitalize)` it is then